How to write a deceptive cadence when you use an incomplete V7 chord?

As you can see here, the alto A is in a bit of a jam. Can't go up else parallel octaves will result and down will create an overlap with the tenor. Is there something I am missing? Do composers just overlap the voices in this case?

Um, not get into a situation where there's a 14th between bass and tenor?

Doubling the fifth in the tenor and alto is obviously the preferable solution to the problem given.  A better solution might lie in revoicing the first chord, but that's obviously beyond the scope of the exercise.
I made a quick survey of a couple deceptive cadences that I could recall.  There are two in the closing chorale of Bach's cantata 140; one has V with no seventh and the other has V7 without any doubling.  Another, Mozart's Ave verum corpus, has a IV6 chord instead of vi, and anyway the preceding V chord isn't V7.  You may have a hard time finding examples of this "in the wild," so to speak.

Yep, you've painted yourself into a corner for sure.  If you want to keep the dominant-seventh chord sound, replace the alto's A with that G.  Move the tenor down to E.  This can resolve more easily now; your tenor can step down and double the D and your alto can still step down to F#.  It's a doubled third in the final chord, which is not ideal, but you might prefer this voice leading.
It's wise to look out for this potential snag in your writing.  Any time you have 4 or more voices and you are using a root-movement of a second you will run into this.  You will always find yourself with two consecutive fifths (here, A-E and B-F#) that need to be filled and never enough "safe paths" to get there.  Putting one chord in an inversion, substituting one chord for a different one, or creatively using suspensions can help too.
